# Wordpress inside a sub folder having low page speed score than root folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have two WordPress installations - one in the root folder and another in a subfolder. However, the website in the subfolder has a significantly lower page speed score compared to the one in the root folder. I'm looking for guidance on how to improve the page speed score for the WordPress website in the subfolder.

Root directory site : https://www.testingbrain.com/

Sub folder site : https://www.testingbrain.com/sap

Comment: Anybody have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick [PageSpeed Insights checkup](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-testingbrain-com-sap/9j8f5g5szc?form_factor=mobile) it seems like backend loading performance—Time to First Byte (TTFB)—is your biggest issue.

You can read up on some general guidance on [Optimizing TTFB](https://web.dev/optimize-ttfb/) but maybe someone else can suggestion something more WordPress-specific.

Comment: Thank You Rick. Previously it was in a root folder of other website. That time there was no issue in speed. After moving that site to this sub folder TTFB issue started.